# Why Node.js can't process the request from Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js

I have strange error and don't know why Node.js don't see url address and always return me 404.

In `Vue.js` application I make post request with `axios` package when user click the button. As you can see from the code I send name of the file in the body of request and user token in the header. I check and both values are not empty.

```
getFile (fileName) {
    axios.post('/csv', {file_name: fileName}, {headers: {'Authorization': this.token}}).then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        this.showAlert('File successfully downloaded.', 'is-success', 'is-top')
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
        this.showAlert('An error occurred while downloading the file.', 'is-danger', 'is-bottom')
    })
}
```

**ERROR:**

```
Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at FtD3.t.exports (createError.js:16)
    at t.exports (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.f.(:3010/anonymous function) (http://localhost:3010/static/js/vendor.1dc24385e2ad03071ff8.js:1312:88758)
```

All requests from browser goes to HTTP server in `Node.js` (`Express.js`). In my case `csv.js` file should process the request. I don't understand in what part of the project problem. By the way other urls works correctly.

**server/bin/www.js:**

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
const app = require('../../app')
const debug = require('debug')('slot:http-server')
const http = require('http')

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.js.
 */
let port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3010')
app.set('port', port)

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */
const server = http.createServer(app)

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */
server.listen(port)
server.on('error', onError)
server.on('listening', onListening)

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */
function normalizePort (val) {
  const port = parseInt(val, 10)
  if (isNaN(port)) {
    return val
  }
  if (port >= 0) {
    return port
  }
  return false
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */
function onError (error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error
  }
  const bind = typeof port === 'string' ? 'Pipe ' + port : 'Port ' + port
  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges')
      process.exit(1)
      break
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use')
      process.exit(1)
      break
    default:
      throw error
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */
function onListening () {
  const address = server.address()
  const bind = typeof address === 'string' ? 'pipe ' + address : 'port ' + address.port
  debug('Listening on ' + bind)
}
```

**app.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');

const locationsRouter = require('./server/routes/locations');
const csvRouter = require('./server/routes/csv');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.use('/api/locations', locationsRouter);
app.use('/csv', csvRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

**server/routes/csv.js:**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

let Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client')
let sftp = new Client()

const config = require('../config')

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  // Set the variable with the name of the file.
  const fileName = req.body.file_name

  // Path to file in remote SFTP server.
  const remotePath = '/reports/' + fileName

  // Local directory where the downloaded file will be placed
  const localePath = path.join(process.env.HOME || process.env.USERPROFILE, 'downloads/' + fileName)

  // Connect to remote SFTP server.
  sftp.connect(config.sftpServer, 'on').then(() => {
    // Download file from remote SFTP server to local machine of the user.
    sftp.fastGet(remotePath, localePath, {}).then(() => {
      res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName)
      res.sendFile(localePath)
      fs.unlink(localePath)
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
})

module.exports = router
```

What can you guys advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In vue, you are doing a post request to /csv, but in your app.js you are defining the /csv route as GET, that is your problem :D

**UPDATE**

If you want this to work with the animation download like chrome 
Take a look at this link
https://gist.github.com/javilobo8/097c30a233786be52070986d8cdb1743

Comment: Just want to post the same :+1:

Comment: Well, if I change `router.get` to `router.post` Node.js raise error: `Error: Request failed with status code 500`. Can you check my `csv.js` file and say whats wrong?

Comment: I change my `csv.js` file. Can you check my post again please. I need to send downloaded file as response.

Comment: What's the error that you are getting in the console.log?

Comment: `fastGet` method which you can see in `csv.js` file download file from remore SFTP server to local machine of the user. I need to send that file as response to browser. Is it possible to send it? So what I need to change in Vue.js code?

Comment: replace your stfp code with this and try if it works.

Comment: return sftp.connect(config.sftpServer)
 .then(() => {
        return sftp.fastGet(remotePath, localePath);
    })
 .then((data) => {
       res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName)
    res.end(data)
 }

Comment: @PedroSilva let me try to explain the problem. For example when user want to download something from browser, they usually see that file is downloaded inside the browser (on bottom side in Chrome for example). I want the same behavior. Right now my code and your code download the file from remote server to local user computer in backend and user cannot see the behavior which I described to you earlier. Of course I can show message to user that file successfully downloaded but he/she will have to do additional steps to find this file.

Comment: I think I need change Vue.js code. Is it possible in Vue.js open file from file system, or download it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187389/discussion-between-pedro-silva-and-nurzhan-nogerbek).